# Setting up UIView subclass as an IBOutlet in a UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I have this UIView subclass that returns a view with a gradient background

```
class GradientView: UIView {

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    var currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSaveGState(currentContext);

    var colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    var startColor = UIColor(red: 195/255, green: 33/255, blue: 121/255, alpha: 1);
    var startColorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(startColor.CGColor)
    var endColor = UIColor(red: 134/255, green: 25/255, blue: 101/255, alpha: 1);
    var endColorComponents = CGColorGetComponents(endColor.CGColor)

    var colorComponents
    = [startColorComponents[0], startColorComponents[1], startColorComponents[2], startColorComponents[3], endColorComponents[0], endColorComponents[1], endColorComponents[2], endColorComponents[3]]

    var locations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

    var gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace,&colorComponents,&locations,2)

    var startPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.bounds.height)
    var endPoint = CGPointMake(self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(currentContext,gradient,startPoint,endPoint, 0)

    CGContextRestoreGState(currentContext);
}
```

In Interface Builder, in one of the UITableView's prototype cells I have a GradientView. I am ctrl-dragging to the prototype cell's UITableViewCell subclass the gradient as an IBOutlet.

```
class GenericResultsHeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var headerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerIcon: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: GradientView!

}
```

However I am getting:
`Cannot override mutable property 'backgroundView' of type 'UIView?' with covariant type 'GradientView!'`

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that UITableViewCell already has a property called backgroundView and your IBOutlet would override it.

[For reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/backgroundView)

What i would do is to override the designated initialiser for UIStoryboard instantiated cells. My subclass would probably look like this:

```
class GenericResultsHeaderCell: UITableViewCell {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.backgroundView = GradientView(frame: self.frame)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the backgroundView will be underneath the content view so you may not see it.